# Determing what cells covered by a single contiuous array formula

Tags: excel

Suppose in cells B1:B3 I have the following formula:

```
{=A1:A6}
```

Then cells B4:B6 I enter the same formula.  The result will look like this:

```
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  1
5  2
6  3
```

But casual inspection of the formulas would falsely suggest that B1:B6 are a single array formula, like this:

```
A  B
1  {=A1:A6}
2  {=A1:A6}
3  {=A1:A6}
4  {=A1:A6}
5  {=A1:A6}
6  {=A1:A6}
```

In this contrived example, it's easy to look at the results and see that there are really two array formulas in B.  Is there a reliable way to check this in situations where the data doesn't make it so obvious?

Ideally I would like to see a box around B1:B3 and one around B4:B6 showing that there are distinct blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with the best I could find -- would still love to see a better answer:

You can select a cell in a multi-cell array formula and hit Ctrl+/.  This will cause the whole multi-cell array formula to be selected.